# Angularjs $scope.$apply(fn) keeps recalling itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an web app with Angular. I am trying to update a scope variable, but I needed to use $apply to allow it to update the DOM. However, now it calls it over and over. And I can't get it to stop. I've been reading everywhere and I can't find a good place to tell me how to stop this function from calling itself again. It only needs to be called once.

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
     $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
});
```

**Solution:**

Instead of using $scope.$apply, the comment below suggested to use $timeout(fn) instead and that word out find.

Comment: You need to show us more, because I can't reproduce your problem with just this piece of code. A fiddle would be nice.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to put one up real quick

Comment: @Beterraba is right (Nice nickname by the way). And I would think to myself why I need to `$apply`...

Comment: The recommend way of doing this is to use $timeout(fn);